# How can I copy an array of arrays into clipboard using javascript

Tags: javascript

I can copy a string into the clipboard using code below:

```js
function copyText(text) {

  if (navigator.clipboard) { // default: modern asynchronous API
    return navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  } else if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.setData) {     // for IE11
    window.clipboardData.setData('Text', text);
    return Promise.resolve();
  } else {
    // workaround: create dummy input
    const input = h('input', { type: 'text' });
    input.value = text;
    document.body.append(input);
    input.focus();
    input.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    input.remove();
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

The issue is I want to copy a representation of an array (actually an array of arrays).

So far when I give the function an array it just copy the elements and separate them with a semi colon!

How can I copy an array of arrays into clipboard using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your function, just use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```js
const arr = [[1,2],[1,2]];
copyText(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

```js
// then wherever you have them pasting
JSON.parse(pastedText);
```

Full Example:

```js
function copyText(text) {
  if (navigator.clipboard) { // default: modern asynchronous API
    return navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  } else if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.setData) {     // for IE11
    window.clipboardData.setData('Text', text);
    return Promise.resolve();
  } else {
    // workaround: create dummy input
    const input = h('input', { type: 'text' });
    input.value = text;
    document.body.append(input);
    input.focus();
    input.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    input.remove();
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}



click.onclick = ()=>{
const arr = [[1,2],[1,2]];
copyText(JSON.stringify(arr));
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Paste Here!">
<button id="click">Click to copy!</button>
```